# How to filter items in array by region?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-cloud-platform, filter

So I'm getting incidents reports from Google Cloud API and displaying it. I'm trying to only display the ones that are happening on the US.
As you can see, the raw data from the API is like this:

[image]

I want to filter it, so I only get the ones that have us on it, how can I do it? This is the code now:

```
export const getGoogleStatus = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents.json')
    console.log('Raw Data: ', response.data)
    const status = response.data.map((e) => {
        return {
            name: e.affected_products.map((e) => {
                return e.title
            }),
            status: e.most_recent_update.status,
            location: e.most_recent_update.affected_locations.map((e) => {
                return e.title
            }),
        }
    })
    return status
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method in order to filter elements that doesn't match a specific criteria. Since you want only the items that are in the US, therefore you can check if it includes its code using `include`, which I believe it will be `(us-` as a substring.

```
export const getGoogleStatus = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents.json')
    console.log('Raw Data: ', response.data)
    const status = response.data.map((e) => {
        return {
            name: e.affected_products.map((e) => {
                return e.title
            }),
            status: e.most_recent_update.status,
            location: e.most_recent_update.affected_locations.map((e) => {
                return e.title
            }).filter((e)=>e.includes('(us-')), //filters all elements that doesn't include '(us-' as a substring
        }
    })
    return status
}
```

Comment: It now filters it correctly, thanks a lot! Do you know how to ONLY RETURN the ones that have data in location? I mean, don't return the ones that are not US region

Comment: @JuanVergara I didn't really get "the ones that have data in location". Can you please mention the expected output how does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a static JSON file so you can use `filter()` to check if the location contains `(us-` as shown below:

```
location: e.most_recent_update.affected_locations.map((e) => {
  return e.title
}).filter((r) => r.includes("(us-"))
```

If you want `affected_products` in US, then you can use the same filter on `e.affected_products` itself and check if `affected_locations` has any location from US.